# SQL query to ignore case in where condition

Tags: sql

I am trying to run below SQL query.$1 would be the passing parameter. I would need that to be case insensitive. for eg:

test.sql server1.net and test SERVER1.NET ( Both values should be taken, I think now the below query only takes the parameter in lowercase by default)
So my requirement is, irrespective of the case, whatever values I have given, query should process. Please help ?

```
select * from act_msgs m,node_name nn
where msg_name like '%test%'
and nn.node_name = '$1'
```

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, PostGreSQL, Oracle?

Comment: What DBMS / programming language do you use? SQL is the global language but not a specific dialect like MySQL, Oracle, ...

Comment: One possible solution is to make it lower at both ends when comparing

where lower(col)=lower('val')

Comment: @MatBailie: nitpicking. it's PostgreSQL (or simply Postgres). There is no capital G in the name.

Answer (score 0):

In Tsql you can use [UPPER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms180055.aspx) function as:

```
declare @varTest varchar(100);
Set @varTest = Upper('test')
select * from act_msgs m,node_name nn
where Upper(msg_name) like '%' + varTest +'%'
and nn.node_name = '$1'
```

Comment: Using functions in where may reduce the performance, so it's preferable to avoid.

Comment: True, but using upper() or lower() in the where clause really slows down production.  It's almost worthwhile storing an upper or lower case version of the name to use for searches as well as the mixed case version for display.

Comment: Or just a case insensitive collation sequence.  Without knowing the RDBMS things are speculation.  But specifically to SQL Server, I'd recommend a ci collation long before I'd advocate searching strings masked by an UPPER() function call.

Answer (score 0):

By default Sql Server is case insensitive. So it makes no difference whether the value supplied is in upper case or lower case. It will be processed.
The following example will make it clear:

```
DECLARE @MessageName    VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Message TABLE
(
    [ID]            INT
,   [MessageName]   VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Message
(
    [ID]
,   [MessageName]
)
VALUES
    (1, 'first message')
,   (2, 'SECOND MESSAGE')
,   (3, 'Third Message')
```

Now whether you set the variable in upper case or lower case, the query will return output:

```
SET @MessageName = 'FIRST MESSAGE'
SELECT * FROM @Message WHERE [MessageName] = @MessageName
```

Result:

### **ID    MessageName**

1   *first message*

```
SET @MessageName = 'second message'
SELECT * FROM @Message WHERE [MessageName] = @MessageName
```

### **ID    MessageName**

2   *SECOND MESSAGE*